# How to read data from csv file if all the values are in the same column?

Tags: python, list, pandas, csv

I have a csv file in the following format:

```
"age","job","marital","education","default","balance","housing","loan"
58,"management","married","tertiary","no",2143,"yes","no"
44,"technician","single","secondary","no",29,"yes","no"
```

However, instead of being separated by tabs (different columns), they all lie in the same first column. When I try reading this using pandas, the output gives all the values in the same list instead of a list of lists.

My code:

```
dataframe = pd.read_csv("marketing-data.csv", header = 0, sep= ",")
dataset = dataframe.values
print(dataset)
```

O/p:

```
[[58 'management' 'married' ..., 2143 'yes' 'no']
 [44 'technician' 'single' ..., 29 'yes' 'no']]
```

What I need:

```
[[58, 'management', 'married', ..., 2143, 'yes', 'no']
 [44 ,'technician', 'single', ..., 29, 'yes', 'no']]
```

What is it I am missing?

Comment: Your text says you want columns separated by tabs, but your expected output suggests you want commas.  How can you tell you *aren't* getting tabs from printing?

Comment: what's the difference between what you get and what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are confused by the `print()` output which doesn't show commas.

Demo:

```
In [1]: df = pd.read_csv(filename)
```

Pandas representation:

```
In [2]: df
Out[2]:
   age         job  marital  education default  balance housing loan
0   58  management  married   tertiary      no     2143     yes   no
1   44  technician   single  secondary      no       29     yes   no
```

Numpy representation:

```
In [3]: df.values
Out[3]:
array([[58, 'management', 'married', 'tertiary', 'no', 2143, 'yes', 'no'],
       [44, 'technician', 'single', 'secondary', 'no', 29, 'yes', 'no']], dtype=object)
```

Numpy `string` representation (result of `print(numpy_array)`):

```
In [4]: print(df.values)
[[58 'management' 'married' 'tertiary' 'no' 2143 'yes' 'no']
 [44 'technician' 'single' 'secondary' 'no' 29 'yes' 'no']]
```

**Conclusion:** your CSV file has been parsed correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really see a difference between what you want and what you get.. but parsing the csv file with the built in csv module give your desired result

```
import csv
with open('file.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
     spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='|')
     print list(spamreader)
```

[

['age', 'job', 'marital', 'education', 'default', 'balance', 'housing', 'loan'],

['58', 'management', 'married', 'tertiary', 'no', '2143', 'yes', 'no'],

['44', 'technician', 'single', 'secondary', 'no', '29', 'yes', 'no']

]